# Can someone verify my proof regarding $\limsup(a_{n}+b_{n})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Given two bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, I want to prove that $\limsup(a_{n}+b_{n}) \leq \limsup(a_{n}) + \limsup(b_{n})$

I did a proof by counterexample. Suppose $\limsup(a_{n}+b_{n}) > \limsup(a_{n}) + \limsup(b_{n})$. Suppose for arbitrarily large n, $a_{n}=\limsup(a_{n})$ and $b_{n}=\limsup(b_{n})$. This is our "best case scenario", i.e. $a_{n}+b_{n}$ is maximal for large $n$ and $a_{n}+b_{n} = \limsup(a_{n})+\limsup(b_{n})$. In this case, there would be no value $k>n$ such that $a_{n}+b_{n} > \limsup(a_{n})+\limsup(b_{n})$, so $\limsup(a_{n}+b_{n}) \leq \limsup(a_{n})+\limsup(b_{n})$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $\limsup(a_{n}+b_{n}) \leq \limsup(a_{n})+\limsup(b_{n})$.

Comment: What if the sequences don't have maximal terms?

Comment: Use \limsup throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument does not work, as you cannot assume the sequence is eventually constant and maximal. What you could do instead is the following.

Recall the definition

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}x_k.$$

We can thus start by showing that

$$\sup_{k\geq n}(a_k+b_k)\leq\sup_{k\geq n}a_k+\sup_{k\geq n}b_k.$$

Recall the result which states that if $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are non-empty and bounded, then

$$\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B,$$

where $A+B=\{x+y:x\in A\land y\in B\}$ (there are other posts here you could refer to for a proof of this), and the result which states that if $C\subseteq D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are non-empty and bounded, then

$$\sup C\leq\sup D.$$

In particular notice that

$$\{a_k+b_k:k\geq n\}\subseteq\{a_{k_1}+b_{k_2}:k_1,k_2\geq n\}=\{a_k:k\geq n\}+\{b_k:k\geq n\},$$

and so

$$\sup_{k\geq n}(a_k+b_k)\leq\sup_{\substack{k_1\geq n\\k_2\geq n}}(a_{k_1}+b_{k_2})=\sup_{k\geq n}a_k+\sup_{k\geq n}b_k.$$

Since this holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can let $n\to\infty$ in this inequality and obtain the desired result.